# SSL error when accessing site blog's redirect url directly with https://

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, redirect, ssl, routes

My site is SSL-enabled and has a Wordpress blog at `https://mysite.com/blog` that I am redirecting in my routes to `http://blog.mysite.com` with the following line:

```
#routes.rb    
get 'blog', to: redirect('http://blog.mysite.com/'), as: 'blog'
```

On my homepage I have a link in the footer whose URL is formatted as `https://mysite.com/blog` and which, when clicked, redirects the user to `blog.mysite.com`.

The problem is that if a user types the redirect URL `https://blog.mysite.com` into their address bar directly, rather than clicking the link for/directly typing the original pre-redirect URL `https://mysite.com/blog`, the SSL certificate doesn't match correctly (not sure how to state this) and the user will get a "This may not be the website you're looking for" error and then the https:// padlock symbol with a red X over it in the address bar.

Typing `http://blog.mysite.com` directly into the address bar (rather than https://) works fine.

There's not actually a problem (first of all because the blog doesn't really need SSL to begin with) but it looks bad if a user types `https://blog.mysite.com` directly and thinks there may be some kind of security problem.

I don't know enough about SSL to understand why this is happening. Is there a way for me to prevent it while still displaying the site in the address bar as `blog.mysite.com`?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes, but you need a different SSL certificate.

Long answer: Your SSL certificate (your "key") contains the site name for which the certificate is valid. If the name in the address bar and the name in the certificate do not match, the browser displays the warning.

This allows people to make sure they are actually connected to the correct site - nobody can make a fake `mysite.com` without having your certificate.

In your case, it seems that the certificate is only valid for `mysite.com` but **not** for `blog.mysite.com`. It is possible to have a "wildcard" certificate that is also valid for `*.mysite.com`. In that case the certificate would also work for `blog.mysite.com` or `anything.mysite.com`.

The people who made your original certificate can probably make you one that works. Depending on who they are, this may or may not cost you extra money. You will also have to install the new certificate to your system.

Comment: When I click to view info on the certificate, I see "Starfield Root Certificate Authority - G2." Nested under that is "Starfield Secure Certificate Authority - G2." Nested under that is "mysite.com." Under mine it says "Expires Feb 14, 2015" yet there is also a warning "This certificate has been revoked" (???). When you mention "the people who made your original certificate" would that be Starfield? (I inherited this site and haven't setup SSL before so am pretty lost)

Comment: It is totally possible that the certificate was revoked due to one of the recent vulnerabilities (heartbleed). In that case you should **really** get a new certificate and install it. There are a number of vendors for certificates that you could use, maybe someone else can recommend one. How it is installed depends very much on your setup...

Comment: I don't understand if it's actually been revoked because when I visit "mysite.com" the SSL icon is green and the certificate info says that it's valid. I only get these other problems when pointing my browser directly to "https://blog.mysite.com." Right now I think I mostly need to know whether I need to talk to the company that is hosting the blog or some other SSL-certificate issuing company.

Comment: Not every browser actually checks the revocation and warns the user. There are [articles on the interweb that explain that](http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2013/05/13/how-certificate-revocation-doesnt-work-in-practice.html).

Comment: Ok, I've been doing a bit more research and it seems like wildcard certs are very expensive compared to normal ones and a big overkill for my situation since I only need one subdomain covered. In this case would the best solution be just to purchase another regular ssl certificate and install it in the cPanel of the shared hosting service I'm using for the blog?